# How (should I) to look for email uniquess in a registration system vs mail providers policies?

Tags: email, google

I'm implementing a registration system where I would care of having a clean DB with only unique email addresses.

uniquenes could be simply obtained by comparing email addresses strings.

But considering what various email providers policies, allowing you to use same address e.g. inserting dots or plus signs...

Resource: http://www.businessinsider.com/why-the-dot-in-your-gmail-address-doesnt-matter?IR=T

I there around any best practice to limit this behaviour?
Should this be managed Or should I really worry about this?
This problem could also be raised & related on a use case where a user creates multiple aliases for the same email account...and then maybe the battle is already lost and principle is just: it is up to them if they like to receive everything in one box....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate email addresses. How heavily should I normalize them?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/338955/finding-duplicate-email-addresses-how-heavily-should-i-normalize-them)

Comment: You cannot possible hope to cover how various organisations present email addresses. I worked for a company where there were at least 3 presentations for name and surname that could be used and also a mainly numeric one which was used internally.